# Attribute Error while trying to access a MYSQL table : SQLAlchemy Django

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy

I am getting the below attribute error while trying to access data from MySQL database using SQL Alchemy.

```
qry = sa.select(ref_table.c.Trade_Date, ref_table.c.Open, ref_table.c.High, ref_table.c.Low, ref_table.c.Close
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "E:\theparams\theparamsenv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\base.py", line 1634, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError(key) from err
AttributeError: Trade_Date
```

The table has data for trade_date column and you can find the table description below.
[image: Table Stucture]

```
table_name = "core_historicaldata"
engine = sa.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://' + str(str(data_base.user) + ':' + str(data_base._password)) + '@'+ str(data_base._host) + ':' +
                                   str(data_base._port) + '/' + str(data_base.database), echo=False)
ref_table = sa.Table(table_name, sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)
qry = sa.select(ref_table.c.Trade_Date, ref_table.c.Open, ref_table.c.High, ref_table.c.Low, ref_table.c.Close).where(ref_table.c.Symbol == stock)
data = pd.read_sql_query(qry, engine)
engine.dispose()
```

I think this is something to do with primary key or index. Please advise

Comment: SQLA reflects the column name as-is from the database, and Python is case-sensitive.  If the column name is `trade_date` in the database then you must use `ref_table.c.trade_date`, _not_ `ref_table.c.Trade_Date`.